# The same output for different values of how in merging 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am testing merging on below dataframes:

[image]

[image]

From below line of code:

```
merge1 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='HPI',how='inner')
```

I expected this output:

[image]

However instead I have:

[image]

Moreover, it doesn't matter which option I use in how parameter('inner', 'outer','left','right') I always get the same output.
It is sure, that I do not unserstant properly merging in accordance to parameter how. Could somebody please explain, why I get the same outputs for all options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with duplicates in `HPI` column. There is possible create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
merge1 = pd.concat([df1.set_index('HPI', append=True), 
                    df2.set_index('HPI', append=True)], axis=1).reset_index(level=1)

print (merge1)
      HPI  Int_rate  US_GDP_Thousands  Low_tier_HPI  Unemployment
2001   80         2                50            50             7
2002   85         3                55            52             8
2003   88         2                65            50             9
2004   85         2                55            53             6
```

Or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `index` and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by 2 columns:

```
merge1 = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(),df2.reset_index(),on=['index','HPI'])
print (merge1)
   index  HPI  Int_rate  US_GDP_Thousands  Low_tier_HPI  Unemployment
0   2001   80         2                50            50             7
1   2002   85         3                55            52             8
2   2003   88         2                65            50             9
3   2004   85         2                55            53             6
```

Last solution if is possible index values are duplicated too:

```
df1 = df1.assign(new=df1.groupby('HPI').cumcount())
df2 = df2.assign(new=df2.groupby('HPI').cumcount())

merge1 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['new','HPI']).drop('new',axis=1)
print (merge1)
   HPI  Int_rate  US_GDP_Thousands  Low_tier_HPI  Unemployment
0   80         2                50            50             7
1   85         3                55            52             8
2   88         2                65            50             9
3   85         2                55            53             6
```

Answer (score 0):

From your result it appears you just need to perform a left merge on 2 columns ('HPI', 'Low_teri_HPI'), instead of just 'HPI'.

```
merge1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['HPI', 'Low_tier_HPI'], how='left')
```

This should produce your desired result.

If there are repeated keys in `df2`, you can drop duplicates via `df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['HPI', 'Low_tier_HPI'])` first. In your minimal example, this is not necessary.